# writing a function for dictionary of dictionary in python

Tags: python

im trying to create a dictionary within a dictionary.so that the format of the output looks like the below example.

```
d={list1:{list2:list3}}
```

The data looks like this and the len(data)=500

```
199 5.5 0.875
192 2.5 -0.345
192 7.5 -0.248
192 72.5 -0.912
192 7.5 -0.217
199 2.5 -0.494
199 87.5 -0.955
```

i need to write a small function that returns a nested dictionary . i have referred the previous posts in stackoverflow.for some reason my implementation doesnt work.
what i tried so far:

```
def nested(filename):
    with open(filename) as file: 
        d={}      
        for line in file:
            word = line.split()
            st1=word[0]         
            st2=word[1]
            st3=word[2]
            d[st1]={}
            d[st1][st2]=st3
            #print1(d)#  prints all values in the dict
    #print2(d)#prints only few values
    return d
```

when i execute the function for creatinf just a normal dictionary with key:value i have no issues.but when i try to create a nested dictionary the function doesnt return the values. it just returns a single line from the dictionary
like

```
 {199:{ 87.5: -0.955}}
```

Comment: You are _resetting_ the value of `d` to a blank dict (`{}`) for every line in your file.  Move `d={}` _before_ the `for`.

Comment: i tried by executing it moving d above for, and also above with, it doesnt return..

Comment: yes removed them..but the function still doesnt return all the value

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. You might want to read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: The first column values are not unique.  Is it okay that the nested dictionary only has one entry per key (such as {199:{ 87.5: -0.955}} for 199, overwriting previous values with the same key (i.e. {199: {2.5 -0.494}}.  Otherwise you will need a list of nested dictionaries for each key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a condition on `dict` and `list` initialization:

```
def nested(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        d={}
        for line in file:
            word = line.split()
            st1=word[0]
            st2=word[1]
            st3=word[2]
            # conditional initialisation:
            if st1 not in d:
              d[st1]={}
            if st2 not in d[st1]:
              d[st1][st2]=[]
            d[st1][st2].append(st3)
    return d
```

The result would be as follows:

```
{
    '199': {
        '5.5': ['0.875'],
        '2.5': ['-0.494'],
        '87.5': ['-0.955']},
    '192': {
        '2.5': ['-0.345'], 
        '7.5': ['-0.248', '-0.217'], 
    '72.5': ['-0.912']}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others explained in comments, you are resetting d in every loop also you can't use dictionary because there are not unique keys. (see, there are same values in filename) but you can use dictionary for inside.

For example: `('199', {'5.5': '0.875'})`. I have used tuples and tuple's second value is dictionary.

**My implementation:**

```
def nested(filename):
    tuple_list = []
    with open(filename) as file:       
        for line in file:
            word = line.split()
            st1=word[0]         
            st2=word[1]
            st3=word[2]
            nested_dic = {st2:st3}
            tuple_list.append((st1,nested_dic))
    return tuple_list
```

Comment: I don't think you end up with nested dict this way

Comment: I am getting tuples of list. And tuple's second values are dictionary. I can't create nested dictionaries because there is not unique keys. See filename content.